# Preserving Word Document Formatting when Reading Content for Gmail Draft in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, gmail-api, docx

I am using Excel VBA to create Gmail drafts via the Gmail API. The code works well, but I am facing an issue when trying to read the content of a Word document file as the email body. The formatting, such as paragraphs and font size, is not preserved, and the text is merged into a single paragraph in plain text mode.

I attempted to convert the Word document to HTML and copy its content to the email body to maintain paragraph formatting. However, in the final result, when viewed in the recipient's inbox, the email body appears as a paragraph with numerous HTML tags.

Here is a snippet of the code I am currently using to read the Word document and construct the email message:

```
 Dim emailBody As String
               
                ' Read the email body from the Word document
                emailBody = ReadWordDocument(wb.Path & "\" & folderNum & "\email.docx")
 ' Construct the email message
                Dim message As String
                message = "To: " & recipient & vbCrLf
                message = message & "Subject: " & subject & vbCrLf
                message = message & "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=foo_bar_baz" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                message = message & "--foo_bar_baz" & vbCrLf
                message = message & "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                message = message & "Dear " & position & " " & firstName & " " & lastName & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                message = message & emailBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

Function ReadWordDocument(ByVal filePath As String) As String
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(filePath)
    
    ' Save the document as HTML
    Dim htmlFilePath As String
    htmlFilePath = Left(filePath, Len(filePath) - 4) & ".html"
    
    objDoc.SaveAs2 htmlFilePath, 10 ' wdFormatHTML = 10
    
    ' Read the HTML content
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open htmlFilePath For Input As fileNumber
    fileContent = Input$(LOF(fileNumber), fileNumber)
    Close fileNumber
    
    ' Delete the temporary HTML file
    Kill htmlFilePath
    
    ReadWordDocument = fileContent
    
    objDoc.Close
    objWord.Quit
End Function
```

These are the functions for creating and updating the draft and base64:

```
    ' Function to create a draft email
    Function CreateDraftEmail(ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal recipient As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal message As String)
        Dim url As String
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts"
        
        Dim headers As Object
        Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & accessToken
        headers("Content-Type") = "application/json"
        
        Dim payload As String
        payload = "{""message"": {""raw"": """ & EncodeBase64(message) & """}}"
        
        Dim response As String
        SendRequestWithHeaders "POST", url, headers, payload, response
        
        Dim draftID As String
        draftID = GetJsonValue(response, "id")
        
        ' Update the draft ID in the Excel worksheet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supervisors")
        
        Dim rowNum As Integer
        rowNum = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim recipientColumn As Range
        Set recipientColumn = ws.Range("E2:E" & rowNum)
        
        Dim draftIDColumn As Range
        Set draftIDColumn = ws.Range("O2:O" & rowNum)
        
        Dim recipientCell As Range
        Set recipientCell = recipientColumn.Find(recipient, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        Dim draftIDCell As Range
        If Not recipientCell Is Nothing Then
            Set draftIDCell = draftIDColumn.Cells(recipientCell.Row - recipientColumn.Cells(1).Row + 1)
            draftIDCell.Value = draftID
        End If
        
         ' Return the draft status
        If draftID <> "" Then
            CreateDraftEmail = "Success"
        Else
            CreateDraftEmail = "DraftError"
        End If
        
    End Function
    
    ' Function to update a draft email
    Function UpdateDraftEmail(ByVal accessToken As String, ByVal draftID As String, ByVal recipient As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal message As String)
        Dim url As String
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/" & draftID
        
        Dim headers As Object
        Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & accessToken
        headers("Content-Type") = "application/json"
        
        Dim payload As String
        payload = "{""message"": {""raw"": """ & EncodeBase64(message) & """}}"
        
        Dim response As String
        SendRequestWithHeaders "PUT", url, headers, payload, response
        
       ' Return the draft status
        If InStr(response, """id"":") > 0 Then
            UpdateDraftEmail = "Success"
        Else
            UpdateDraftEmail = "DraftError"
        End If
        
    End Function
    
    ' Function to send an HTTP request with headers
    Sub SendRequestWithHeaders(ByVal method As String, ByVal url As String, ByRef headers As Object, ByVal payload As String, ByRef response As String)
        Dim objHTTP As Object
        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        
        objHTTP.Open method, url, False
        
        Dim header As Variant
        For Each header In headers.Keys
            objHTTP.setRequestHeader header, headers(header)
        Next header
        
        objHTTP.send payload
        
        response = objHTTP.responseText
    End Sub

' Function to encode text as base64
Function EncodeBase64(ByVal inputText As String) As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    arrData = StrConv(inputText, vbFromUnicode)
    
    Dim objXML As Object
    Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    
    Dim objNode As Object
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("base64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    
    EncodeBase64 = Replace(objNode.Text, vbLf, "")
End Function
```

Is there a way to modify this code or find an alternative approach to properly preserve the font size and paragraph structure of the Word document while reading its content for the email body? I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples that can help me solve this problem and maintain the original formatting (such as Gmail UI) of the Word document in the email draft and maintain its proper format in the recipient's system.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Might help to include the code to send the message, to help anyone who wants to try this out.

Comment: @TimWilliams Actually I only want to create the draft and there is no need to send the message. However, I edited the question and added additional functions which are responsible for creating and updating draft and base64.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message  looks like the POST'ed "message" object is more complex for multipart mails?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your comment. Yes, I think so. Do u have any reliable, simple and efficient idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with this.